# replacing a string in a list of lists

Tags: python, matrix, replace

I'm trying to generate an alphabet soup. I've created the grid(list of lists) and am now trying to replace letters in the grid, but i'm having some trouble with replacing it.

The code to generate the grid:

```
file = open('gerarsopa.txt')
x = file.readline().split()
l = []
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
for linha in range(0,int(x[0])):
    temp = []
    for coluna in range(0,int(x[1])):
        temp.append(random.choice(alphabet.upper()))
    l.append(temp)
for row in l:
    print(" ".join(row))
file.close()
```

The program takes in a file in which the dimensions, and letters that I am going to have replace later on, are on.

I don't know how to replace letter by letter the words in the grid, I only came up with a way to replace words with in a single point in the grid:

```
def substituir():
    file = open('gerarsopa.txt')
    string = file.read().split()
    palavras = string[2:]
    l[random.randint(0,int(x[1]))] = palavras[2]
```

Obviously the words can't go out of the grid, have to be complete, and can't overlap with another word with a letter that isn't used in both words.

The output should be something like this:

```
e n k j d q d y p
b R E D k c d q f
z p o h k t y r t
a c h G n m e f x
p f k b R g f j l
b g j y v E n i c
s e p f o r E v w
E U L B k w t N n
m p q k y f a h i
```

The upper case letters are an example of how the words should stay in the grid. The are randomly put in the grid
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: It's a little bit difficult to understand your problem from description alone. Could you give some example input and acceptable output data?

Comment: Are you trying to solve the same problem as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41729990/how-to-generate-a-crossword-grid-that-enables-words-using-the-same-letter)?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? replace letters in the string with other random letters? or are you trying to create some type of encryption that is reversible?

Comment: I'm trying to put words in the grid randomly...I've edited the question

Comment: @MiguelLuís and can we assume that the words to be put into the grid will be in a list such as ["red", "green", "brown"] ?

Comment: @Gaelephor yes!

Comment: @MiguelLuís I will answer this question, ive got part of the code working, ill get the answer up tonight, but ive got to go grab dinner. sorry for the delay.